# Sort dates file python

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

I have a file that contains dates and tasks in this form

```
(datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 20, 0, 0), 'laundry')
(datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'exam ')
```

how can I display the tasks due within a certain date ( ex. due within a week ) in this format ?

```
20/05/2014: laundry
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the lines in the file sorted in order of datetime?

Comment: Yes they are sorted in order of datetime.

Comment: The title of the question is about sorting dates, but the body of the question asks about displaying dates.  There is a mismatch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is a list of tuples like this:

```
date_list = [(datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 20, 0, 0), 'laundry'), (datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'exam '), (datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'grocery'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 20, 0, 0), 'tv')]
```

- You can get the sorted list based on the dates by doing:

  ```
  sorted_dates = sorted(date_list, key=lambda x: str(x[1]), reverse=True)
  ```

  Here, you are passing the string representation of the dates as the key to the `sorted` function which effectively translates sorting dates to a sorting of strings. This gives you:

  ```
  [(datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 20, 0, 0), 'tv'), (datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 20, 0, 0), 'laundry'), (datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 20, 0, 0), 'grocery'), (datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'exam ')]
  ```
- You can format the date in the format you want, using the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method:

  ```
  formatted_dates = [(item[0].strftime("%d/%m/%y"), item[1]) for item in sorted_dates]
  ```

  which gives you:

  ```
  [('20/05/13', 'tv'), ('20/05/14', 'laundry'), ('20/04/14', 'grocery'), ('01/06/14', 'exam ')]
  ```
- Your final output can be obtained by looping the `formatted_dates` as:

  ```
  for date, task in formatted_dates:
  print '{}: {}'.format(date, task)
  ```

  which prints

  ```
  20/05/13: tv
  20/05/14: laundry
  20/04/14: grocery
  01/06/14: exam
  ```

If your data is already sorted, you can skip to step 2.

To get the tasks due in a week, you make use of combination of [timedelta objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and a [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function

```
tasks_in_a_week = filter(lambda x: x[0] > datetime.datetime.now() and x[0] < datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7), sorted_dates)
```

Explanation: `datetime.datetime.now()` gives todays date. `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)` gives the date 7 days from today. So, the above filter function looks for any date in the `sorted_dates` list that falls after today and before 7 days from today i.e., in a week.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !  an other question, if I want to display tasks due witin week how shoul i do it ? @shaktimaan

Answer (score 0):

Given that your tasks is in a file called `mytasks.txt`, this will list all tasks set x days in the future.

**BEWARE:** This code is using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), and if you don't trust your input, you should **not** use this code.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

# Change 7 to your prefered number of days
limit = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)
with open('mytasks.txt') as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        day, task = eval(line)
        # This breaks the loop once a day further ahead arises
        if day > limit:
            break
        print '{}: {}'.format(day.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), task)
```

Given this input:

```
(datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 10, 0, 0), 'chill')
(datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 0, 0), 'out')
(datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 20, 0, 0), 'laundry')
(datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 'exam ')
```

This will be the output:

```
10/04/2014: chill
12/04/2014: out
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a python library for data analysis. Using this library you can read from different file formats as csv and use the TimeSeries class to perform all sort of analysis and operations included the date filtering in your question.

For example, if 'ts' is your timeseries object, to select a time range:

```
hour = ts.index.hour
selector = ((10 <= hour) & (hour <= 13)) | ((20 <= hour) & (hour <= 23))
data = ts[selector]
```